# Using OAuth token in direct JavaScript Twitter API 1.1 call

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

Is there a way to make a direct call to the Twitter v1.1 API passing the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret values in my request?

I know it's not best practice to have these visible, but I'm only running this application locally.

I've tried to pass them directly, but I get an error. Looking into my application settings under the OAuth tab, it shows the "Request URI" using version 1. I can't seem to change this to 1.1, and I'm not even sure if this is the reason for my error.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, it's not possible. JavaScript or otherwise - The secret is used for generating signatures and not only should it never be sent in a URL, but it will achieve nothing.

Twitter's new "application only" authentication implements OAuth2, which uses a bearer token instead of signing. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth That will allow direct calls like you're trying to do, but from JavaScript you'll be doing them cross-domain which means using JSONP or CORS. Twitter support neither.

You're obviously already aware of the security issues, so I don't need to warn you that using bearer tokens in JavaScript is a bad idea. Not least for security reasons, but also rate limits!

You might also like [Flamingo](http://twproxy.eu). It's a proxy for calling the Twitter API from JavaScript. It has security features in place to avoid the obvious dangers. http://twproxy.eu